# How to use Fabric React on an existing Office Web Add-In project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, office365, office-js

It is possible to use `office-ui-fabric-react` on an existing Office Web Add-In project such as Word and Excel web add-in projects? Any preferred way to achieve this?

Upon trying to run this from the root of my project, a lot of dependencies are missing:

```
npm --save install office-ui-fabric-react
```

It seems that it's not possible to use Fabric React without using `create-react-app` and creating a new *"JavaScript > From Existing Node.js code"* project.