# Adding Office UI Fabric react components to Office Add-in web project in visual studio

Tags: office-js, office365-apps, office-ui-fabric, officedev

I am aware that we can use Yo-man and VS template to create office add-in. Yo-man provide more options on building package depending on the framework we select. I am wondering if we can add Office UI fabric react components to the web project of Office add-in in Visual Studio. There is no documentation also on using it in Asp.net core.
Same question here unanswered officially.
[Implementing (Fabric UI) React in an (Office Web Add-In) ASP.net project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47514424/implementing-fabric-ui-react-in-an-office-web-add-in-asp-net-project)

Answer (score 0):

To get started using Fabric React's components in your add-in, perform the following steps.

Step 1 - Create your project with the Yeoman generator for Office

Step 2 - Add a Fabric React component

Step 3 - Add the React component to your add-in

For more information, please see the following link:

[Use Office UI Fabric React in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/using-office-ui-fabric-react)

Comment: As I mentioned clearly in my question, I am not asking how to use in Yo-man based project. I am asking how to do in VS based web project. Can't accept your reply as answer.

Comment: @AshishTrivediPlease see this link:(http://www.devx.com/blog/dev_issues/create-office-365-apps-using-office-ui-fabric-and-react.html)

Comment: your example is copy of https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/wiki/Sample-App of which I am aware. My question is clear. Still my question unanswered.